# Symfony2: Login form and captcha

Tags: symfony, captcha

What is the easiest way to add and validate captcha at login form?

I can add it but I cant validate. You do not need to create additional controller and action to validate user and his pass - Symfony2 make it automatically. But how can I check captcha?

Comment: do you use a captcha provider or do you have your own captcha php script?

Comment: I want to use [recaptcha](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/recaptcha/index.md) from [GenemuFormBundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Captcha to Symfony2 Login Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788828/adding-captcha-to-symfony2-login-page)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764653/is-it-immoral-to-put-a-captcha-on-a-login-form

Comment: This question is not about "Is it immoral to put a captcha on a login form?" and this is not duplicate because that question is about  FOSUserBundle and I asked about native Symfony2 methods and the EASIEST way. Sure I can use my custom listeners/providers/method overriding whatever.. but is there any more easy way to add captcha?

Comment: I do not know who had added block above my question that this question has answer. There is no answer for this question at that topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GenemuFormBundle](http://knpbundles.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle).

Adding captcha to form is simple:

```
$builder
// ...
->add('captcha', 'genemu_recaptcha');
```

Everything is at GenemuFormBundle page.

Comment: Sure. But logic check action is done automatically by Symfony2 and there are only two fields (you can change them in security config: username_parameter and password_parameter) will be used. And captcha parameter not because Symfony2 knows nothing about your captcha. And this is the problem.